# Asynchronous lag in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

I want to set a array in Global variable / rootScope at the time of app load.
I get the data from the Questions service. Since I want to cache the Questions on load time, I tried a lot of things to cache it in rootScope in angular module run function. But there is lag due to asynchronous call everytime. Lag means I get data rendered on page when I open the page for the second time.

One solution tried (which worked) : Return promise in the Questions service all method - But the caveat is that it will call the api eveytime I do a Questions service `all()` method.

Please suggest.

Following is my code:

App.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform, Questions,$rootScope) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });

//starter.services.
//Questions.store().then(function (res) { $rootScope.questions = res.data });

})
```

Controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DotnetCtrl', function ($scope, Questions, $rootScope) {
    $scope.questions = Questions.all();
})
```

Service.js

```
.factory('Questions', function ($http) {
var questions = [];

$http.get('http://api.clickmynotes.com/api/questions').success(function (data) { questions = data; });

return {
    all: function () {
        return questions;

    },
    get: function (id) {
        return questions[id];
    }
}
});
```

Comment: 1 - you need to use resolve in ui-router to get your data before the view. 2 - cache the data in localstorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
.success(function (data) { questions = data; });
```

This means that you're replacing the questions array by a new one when you finally get the data from the server. Since the controller has already called `Questions.all()` when the htttp response comes, it has already obtained the previous, empty array of questions, and this array referenced by the controller stays as is.

What you want instead is populate the array that has already been obtained by the controller:

```
.success(function (data) { 
    angular.forEach(data, function(element) {
        questions.push(element);
    }); 
});
```

That way, the controller gets an empty array initially, and the page doesn't display any element, but as soon as the response from the server is available, the array of questions referenced by the controller is populated, and the view repaints itself, showing the elements.

This technique is the one used by the $resource service.